# In Java, is a++ a postfix operator or an unary operator?

Tags: java, unary-operator, postfix-operator

In Java, is `a++` a postfix operator or an unary operator? In the Operator Precedence from Oracle, it is separated. [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: Specification: [15.14.2. Postfix Increment Operator ++](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) and [15.15. Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15)

Comment: The Java Tutorial is not a reference. The JLS is the only reference. But there is nothing in either place that says it has to be one or the other and not both.

Answer (score 4):

It’s both. It’s a unary operator because it works solely on one term. If it’s x++ then it’s a postfix operator as it’s incremented after using the variable’s value. A prefix unary operator is ++x where it’s incremented before being used. Prefix operators have a higher precedence, but they’re both unary operators

Comment: not by official Specification: [15.15. Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15) - but that is only the *name* used by SUN/Oracle