# In Java, i++ is unary operator or arithmetic operator?

Tags: java, operators, post-increment, unary-operator

I have searched the web and it gives me a divide answer. Some said it is only an unary operator and some said it is an arithmetic operator. Thanks

Comment: It's both. Things can be classified as more than one thing.

Comment: isn't that the same question as [In Java, is a++ a postfix operator or an unary operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60014618/85421)?

Comment: @Kayaman I'd argue that it's also an assignment operator, because it assigns a new value to the variable.

Answer (score 3):

These classifications don't contradict each other.

`++` is an unary operator, as it applies to a single operand.

`++` is also an arithmetic operator, as it applies to a number and performs an arithmetic operation (incrementing the number by one).

Answer (score 1):

I think it won't be a mistake to call `i++` both Arithmetic and Unary Operator.

However, [Oracle doc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) distinguishes and classifies `++` as Unary operator.

Comment: I can't add anything to the answer. It's just a plain answer to the question asked plainly. Not to say much words, if we dive into [§15.14.2 – 15.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) of Oracle Docs, indeed there is a separation between _Postfix_ Increment Operator ++ and Unary Operators. But as the question was about unary _or arithmetic_, my worring of it could be exessive.

Comment: Then, at last, at the beginning of [§15.15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15) it's said (in general?): "The operators +, -, ++, --, ~, ! ... are called the unary operators". The term "unary" then seems not so strict to argue about. Then i++ is also arithmetic because, as Mureinik said, simply, it performs an arithmetic operation